# Installing package npm fails with 404

Tags: javascript

Using the command prompt, I am trying to install mineflayer-autoclicker and it fails.I am writing in Visual Studio Code version of Node.js 18.17.0 LTS. I am trying to install mineflayer-autoclicker using the terminal.

```
npm install --save mineflayer-autoclicker
```

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-couchapp/mineflayer-autoclicker - Not Found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'mineflayer-autoclicker@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Comment: Seems you are using a custom NPM registry? Is that on purpose? If not do `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` and make you don't have a `.npmrc` file in the project or user dir that has a custom registry set.

Answer (score 1):

Run the commands below to solve this issue

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org
npm -g install npm
npm cache clean -f
```

Then run the installation command again.